# Apps script : I can't get correct filter of dates in columns

Tags: date, google-apps-script, filter

I can't get correct filter of dates in columns.

My filter conditions (AND) return months from other years than specified :

```
function filterColumnDates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Filter Dates");

  let monthFilter = sheet.getRange("A4").getValue();
  let yearFilter = sheet.getRange("B4").getValue();  
  Logger.log("monthFilter : "   + monthFilter + " - yearFilter : " + yearFilter)
  
  currentMonth = yearFilter +" "  + monthFilter
  Logger.log("currentMonth : "   + currentMonth )

  var headers = sheet.getRange("A2:NF2").getValues()[0]; 
  //Logger.log("headers : "   + JSON.stringify(headers) + " - " + headers.length) 
  Logger.log("typeof(headers[0]) : " + typeof(headers[0])) // typeof(headers[0]) : object
  
  let filteredDates = headers.filter(c => Utilities.formatDate(c, "GMT", "YYYY")== yearFilter && Utilities.formatDate(c, "GMT", "MMMM") == monthFilter)  
  Logger.log("filteredDates : "   + JSON.stringify(filteredDates) + " filteredDates.length : " + filteredDates.length)  // filteredDates.length : 36

  let colStart = headers.indexOf(filteredDates[0])
  Logger.log("colStart : "   + colStart) // colStart : 0
  
  let colEnd = headers.indexOf(filteredDates[filteredDates.length - 1])
  Logger.log("colEnd : "   + colEnd ) // colEnd : 369
}
```

Script edited to show typeof dates.

Here's the sheet I should have shared :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cE4FRKeVb8EMqm4q9brpjTcLPpZBH4qXud99lto--WQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: what does it returns and what you expect it to return?

Comment: Are you sure your data is dates and not string? If they are dates then use Date getFullYear() and  getMonth()+1 and check against number.

Comment: Could you share an example sheet to check the behavior?  try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that way the community can give you better suggestions.

Comment: Sorry guys sheet is shared now.

@TheWizEd : typeof dates returns object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I saw your showing script, at `let filteredDates = headers.filter(c => Utilities.formatDate(c, "GMT", "YYYY")== yearFilter && Utilities.formatDate(c, "GMT", "MMMM") == monthFilter)`, you are using the week year. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
let filteredDates = headers.filter(c => Utilities.formatDate(c, "GMT", "YYYY")== yearFilter && Utilities.formatDate(c, "GMT", "MMMM") == monthFilter)
```

#### To:

```
let filteredDates = headers.filter(c => Utilities.formatDate(c, "GMT", "yyyy")== yearFilter && Utilities.formatDate(c, "GMT", "MMMM") == monthFilter);
```

#### Reference:

- [Date and Time Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

  > `y`: Year

  > `Y`: Week year

Comment: this helped, kind of ...

Now after correcting the year format, I have extended the date range to check different Month Year combinations.
All yield the correct results, except :
- when it should be returning the very first column, it returns 0 instead of 1
- when it should be returning the very last column, it returns the previous column, instead of the last. 
So, when testing for the first or last month in dates range, these are the only occurences that return wrong results.
I wonder if the function is the correct way to return the correct indexes ?

Comment: @Michel Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new issue, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new issue. So can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand your new issue.

Comment: the problem seem to lie in this line :

var headers = sheet.getRange("A2:OQ2").getValues()[0]

where the dates values are shifted 1 day before ...
probably linked with the default date being formatted like this :
"2021-11-24T23:00:00.000Z" where the hour is "23" instead of 0
...
OK, I realise there was a discrepency between the locale setting and the time zone setting.
I will try to format the dates correctly and it should work.

I'll keep you up to date.

Comment: @Michel Thank you for replying. I'm glad both your 1st issue and 2nd issue were resolved.

Comment: It's not totally resolved :
As the problem lies with the formatting of dates, I started by correcting my locale and timezone settings; also, I tried to get every date in the columns to be set at midnight, by using the formula `=SEQUENCE(1;500;DATEVALUE("21/09/2021 23:00:00"))`
However, the values from the dates range is remaining set à 22:00:00.
Then, I corrected the formatting in the code, using `let filteredDates = headers.filter(c => Utilities.formatDate(c, "GMT+02:00", "YYYY")== yearFilter && Utilities.formatDate(c, "GMT+02:00", "MMMM") == monthFilter) `

Comment: Because the filtering does not use the time, I get the correct filtered array, but with the wrong time value ("23:00:00").
So it's a bit surprising that this code `let colStart = headers.indexOf(filteredDates[0]   ) + 1` returns the correct answer

It was tested for several month year combos + incomplete months at the start and end of the dates range.

I didn't find the way to get a consistent setting of the dates range.

Comment: I would like to get help correct this, as it might lead to future errors for me or someone using similar code. 
The file will remain shared for you to check the tests and see what the logs are returning

Anyways, thank you @Tanaike for helping me.

Comment: @Michel Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I had thought that your 1st question was resolved. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that was part of the problem, so thank you again.
I would appreciate if you have an opinion on the time differences.

PS : I'm not sure I need to close this thread and open a new one for that.

Comment: @Michel Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. So I would like to recommend asking it a new question. By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it? I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Michel, let's try and focus on the main issue. If you have further questions unrelated to the main issue, then feel free to post a new question.

Comment: OK, I'm good with how my script works right now.
I'll ask for help if I encounter a new issue that I can't resolve.
Thanks for all your help guys  ! Especially @Tanaike